# Image view makes app slower

Tags: ios, uiimageview, base64

In my iOS app i have an image view in the Tableviewcell. Before adding that imageview the app was performing smooth. Now its very slow on all devices.

The image is saved in the database as base 64 encode string and it is decoded to image and loaded to the imageview. Decoding is done in background thread.

```
    if(info.image !=nil) {


           UIImage *image = [_imageCache objectForKey:info.threadID];

        if (image)
        {
            // if we have an cachedImage sitting in memory already, then use it

            cell.alignImageView.image = image;
        }
        else
        {
            UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
            spinner.center=cell.alignImageView.center;
            spinner.hidesWhenStopped=YES;
            [cell.alignImageView addSubview:spinner];
            [spinner startAnimating];


            // the get the image in the background

            [self.queue addOperationWithBlock:^{

                // get the UIImage


                NSArray* foo = [info.image componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
                NSString* day = [foo objectAtIndex: 1];

                NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:day];


                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];



                // if we found it, then update UI

                if (image)
                {
                    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                        // if the cell is visible, then set the image

                        if (cell)
                            [spinner stopAnimating];

                            cell.alignImageView.image = image;
                    }];
                    [_imageCache setObject:image forKey:info.threadID];
                }
            }];
        }




    }
```

Comment: consider populating your _imageCache before creating the tableView

Comment: I was already populated that. in view did load. My app is totally slow down now. UI not working well.